# Hardfault_handler with stm32f103

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, cmsis

My code is getting stuck inside the `HAL_Delay()` of my code. On doing the step-into I found out that it is getting inside the `hardfault_handler` and because of which my code gets stuck inside the `HAL_Delay()`.

Now the issue is that I am not able to get why my code is getting inside the `hardfault_handler`, I have not invoked any other interrupt, I also tried creating a project again and then running a simple blink led sketch but still, that does not work out and my code is getting stuck in hardfault_handler whenever I use `HAL_Delay()`.
The controller I am using is STM32F103 Cortex M3.

Comment: Have you correctly initialized the HAL (`HAL_Init`) to enable the SysTick interrupt used by `HAL_Delay`? [UM1850](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/72/52/cc/53/05/e3/4c/98/DM00154093.pdf/files/DM00154093.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00154093.pdf) says the `HAL_Delay` function uses the SysTick interrupt to keep a 1ms time base.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).